# Log of the modified Bessels Function

Tags: bessel-functions

I'm attempting to find a precise as possible approximation to the logarithm of the Modified Bessel Function of the Second Kind:  logIα(x).

Comment: For large values of $x$, it is possible. Is this the case ?

Comment: Over positive values.